# Info not writing to text file

Tags: c#, file-io

For some reason, this method is returning a file with zero bytes. It should create a file and return a list. It will return to the console, but won't write to a file.

Here's the call

```
data.GetStationIDs ("BoulderStations.txt", lat, lon);
```

and here's the method

```
public List<string> GetStationIDs (string filename, string lat, string lon) {

        //specify file name, instructions, and priveleges
        FileStream CurrentDataFile = new FileStream (filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        //create a new stream to write to the file
        StreamWriter CurrentData = new StreamWriter (CurrentDataFile);

        List<string> StationIDList = new List<string>();

        string url = @"http://api.wunderground.com/api/" + wundergroundkey + "/geolookup/q/" + lat + "," + lon + ".json";
        Uri uri = new Uri(url);
        WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri);
        WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        String responseData = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

        var container = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HistoryResponseContainer>(responseData);

        foreach (var pws in container.location.nearby_weather_stations.pws.station) {
            CurrentData.Write (pws.id + " " + pws.lat + " " + pws.lon);
        }

        foreach (var pws in container.location.nearby_weather_stations.pws.station) {
            StationIDList.Add(pws.id);
        }

        return (StationIDList);
```

I have another method where the same approach is working fine.

```
public void GetFiveMinuteData(List<String> StationIDList, String Date, String Filename) {

        //specify file name, instructions, and priveleges
        FileStream CurrentDataFile = new FileStream (Filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        //create a new stream to write to the file
        StreamWriter CurrentData = new StreamWriter (CurrentDataFile);

        foreach (String StationID in StationIDList) { 

            string url = @"http://api.wunderground.com/api/" + wundergroundkey + "/history_" + Date + "/q/pws:" + StationID + ".json";
            Uri uri = new Uri (url);
            WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create (uri);
            WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse ();
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader (response.GetResponseStream ());
            String responseData = streamReader.ReadToEnd ();

            var container = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HistoryResponseContainer> (responseData);

            foreach (var observation in container.history.observations) {

                CurrentData.Write (StationID + " " + Date + " ");
                // This makes easier access to the date. not perfect, but better.
                DateTime date = observation.date.Value;
                DateTime utc = observation.utcdate.Value;

                // whatever you want to do with each observation
                if (date.Minute == 0 || date.Minute % 5 == 0) {
                    CurrentData.Write (date.Hour + ":" + date.Minute + " " + observation.wdird + " " + observation.wspdi);
                }//end if

                CurrentData.Write ("\n");
            } //End foreach observation

        } //end foreach station

        Console.WriteLine ("CurrentDataFile complete!");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines;

```
//specify file name, instructions, and priveleges
        FileStream CurrentDataFile = new FileStream (filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        //create a new stream to write to the file
        StreamWriter CurrentData = new StreamWriter (CurrentDataFile);
```

aren't doing what you expect them to. You never write anything to the file and you never flush the stream. In addition to that, you're code is lacking the proper `using` statements. If you want to continue using the stream reader/write classes look at their docs on msdn, they have good examples which you're not following at all.

Another option would be to simplify your problem and use the following;

```
 File.WriteAllText(aStringWithDataThatIwantInTheFile);

 string fileContents = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\thefilepath.txt");

 string[] fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(AStringWithMyFilePath);

 File.WriteAllLines(AStringArrayGoesHere);
```

Sorry I would work with your current code but there is not much point because I would have to completely rewrite the method and I have no idea what data you actually expect to write to the file because you never actually tell the `StreamWriter` that you allocate to write anything, you just allocate it and then move on to doing other things.

Comment: That's odd, I'm using the same code in another method and it's working fine. I'll update the post to show the other method.

Comment: @WillLuce the fact that your other method works does not make the code any more correct. Look at the example on msdn and read about `IDisposable` and `using` statements if you'd like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx `StreamWriter` implements `IDisposable` which means you either need to allocate within a using statement (what's recommended) or explicitly call the `Dispose` method yourself. I actually didn't notice your `Write` calls at first so you're at least attempting to write but you still never flush the stream or dispose of it.